# How to compile a C++ program that includes external library headers?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to compile a .cpp file that includes an external library header, and that header includes other headers from the said library. Here's the directory structure:

```
ROOT/
├── theLibDir/
│   ├── lib_header1.h # includes "theLibDir/lib_header2.h" and "theLibDir/lib_header3.h"
│   ├── lib_header2.h
│   ├── lib_header3.h
├── src/
│   ├── noob.cpp # includes "theLibDir/lib_header1.h"
```

First, I don't understand why the include paths do not contain `./lib_header{2|3}.h` in the theLibDir or `../theLibDir/lib_header1.` in the src dir.
Then, regarding compiling, so far I tried (from the `ROOT` directory):

```
gcc -o noob src/noob.cpp
gcc -o noob src/noob.cpp theLibDir/lib_header1.h
gcc -o noob src/noob.cpp -ItheLibDir
gcc -o noob src/noob.cpp -LtheLibDir -llib_header1
```

I always get the same error:

```
src/noob.cpp:39:10
fatal error: 'theLibDir/lib_header1.h' file not found
#include "theLibDir/lib_header1.h"
```

Could anyone guide me on this? As you probably got it, I'm really green with C++.

Comment: "without any success" is not a problem description. Where is your code that does the `#include`? What exact errors do you get?

Comment: Make sure `ROOT` is in the include path.

Comment: I just edited problem description in the post.

Comment: BTW, gcc is supposed to be used to compile `c` code. And `g++` for `c++`

Comment: @drescherjm I just tried with `g++` as well, still no luck (same error)

Comment: I expect it won't fix the include directory problem but if you are compiling `c++` code you will expect to get linker errrors.

Comment: Is the library "header only" ?

Comment: @Caduchon there are some .cpp files in the `ROOT`directory as well, including a `lib_header1.cpp `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directive `#include <theLibDir/lib_header1.h>` and the option `-I theLibDir` try to find a file named `ROOT/theLibDir/theLibDir/lib_header1.h`.

Two solutions: use the directive `#include <lib_header1.h>` or put the `ROOT` directory in compilation option `-I`.

Comment: that was it, now I've got a bunch of compilation errors but at least the include path is correct =) Thanks for the help!